# what is the containing block of an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: css

what is the containing block of an absolutely positioned element?  it seems the rule can be a bit complicated...

the spec should be here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details

i want to verify if the following is true:

for simplicity, assume the containing block is a block element (not inline element)...

1) if the absolute positioned element has a closest ancestor that is positioned "non static" (relative, fixed, or absolute), then that ancestor is the containing block.  the absolute positioned element is relative to it.

2) if there is no such ancestor, then the viewport is the containing block, and so the absolute positioned element is relative to the viewport.

no matter what the containing block is above, the width:100% or n% and height:100% or n% are both relative to the containing block.

that's why a

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background:green"></div>
```

right under <body> will cover up the whole viewport exactly -- no more, no less.

we could also use position: fixed, except IE 6 doesn't support it... and so the poor programmer need to use position: absolute instead... (well, not a big deal)

Is that an accurate description of an absolute positioned element?  If so, i think IE 6 and above, FF, Safari, Chrome all follow this behavior accurately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. The containing block is the last *positioned* element. so if you want to explicitly set the container then give it position:relative. Most browsers get this right. CSS doesn't really have a 'viewport', I think the top is the HTML element though don't hold me to that. IE prior to 7 had an unnamed element above HTML though.

Comment: coz the spec says "If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the initial containing block." and "the initial containing block. For continuous media, it has the dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the page area for paged media."

Comment: it is a matter of scope. 

the browser finds the closest parent of your 
absolute position object and so your object 
is absolute positioned relatively to that specific parent.

Comment: closest parent witch has position:relative of course. else, it just obeys the window viewport.

Comment: Window viewport is for all intents and purposes the body tag in most (if not all) cases.

Comment: SpliFF, @vsync, can you provide citations regarding "the last *positioned* element" and "which has position:relative"? According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning, "The section on containing blocks explains when a relatively positioned box establishes a new containing block," but the linked-to section just says "In general, generated boxes act as containing blocks for descendant boxes." I don't see anything in the spec that clearly says the containing block is the closest ancestor with `position: relative`.

Comment: @LarsH - you don't need to go spec-hunting, just try it in your own browser and you will see: http://jsbin.com/utASolU/1/edit

Comment: @vsync: Examples are helpful, but without a spec, it's difficult to draw accurate generalizations.

Comment: @LarsH - Who has time to read specs when I have 9 years of experience with CSS. if you don't know something go ahead and read, I have all the spec inside my head.

Comment: @vsync: If only the spec writers had asked you, it would have saved them a lot of work vs. writing the spec themselves. :-)

Comment: @LarsH - hahaha :D Exactly!

Answer (score 7):

## Summary:

### `position: relative`

Does nothing except set the **positioning context** for all the elements **contained within it**. You can then `position: absolute` any element it contains by setting (typically one or two) values from the possible `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`.

If you give an element with `position: relative` a `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` value, it will shift position accordingly but leave a **blank space** where it would be by default. In other words, it remains within the *document flow* but offset.

### `position: absolute`

To position something absolutely, you need to ask '***absolutely*, but *relative* to which containing element**'? It will either be the entire body (the default) or some other element on the page that is already positioned (usually with `relative` or `absolute` - `fixed` is also useful and [supported in IE 7 but see this bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2007/03/ie7_positionfixed_and_margin_top_bug.html)). It is then taken out of the *document flow* - other elements might appear beneath it, but won't flow around it. If it appears behind another element, you need to set the [`z-index` property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to move it in front.

A common solution is to have a centred container (`margin: 0 auto`) with `position: relative` within which other items are placed with `position: absolute`.

Finally, I like this little [interactive CSS positioning demo](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).